Поясните как работает данный оператор?
Не могу понять работу оператора while. По моей логике inFile >> count возвращает объект inFile, который затем используется с функцией get(). После чего InFile.get() считывает символ оставшейся перевода строки и сравнивает с символом.  Суть такова, что inFile - это объект для чтения с файла(аналог cin). В файле первая строка состоит из цифр и в конце строки символ перевода строки. Почему данный цикл не выполняется ни разу. Меня больше всего интересует как работает этот оператор - его логику. Я просто хочу понять ошибку.
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(filename);
    int count;
    while (((inFile >> count).get()) != '\n')
    cout << count;


"Почему данный цикл не выполняется ни разу." - приведенный кусок кода не позволяет воспроизвести заявленное поведение, но вообще-то, если цикл не выполняется ни разу, то это значит, что условие внутри while было ложным на первой же итерации. И это не удивительно, ведь в коде нет проверок, что файл открылся, что число считано, что символ считан.

Как вы поняли, что while ни разу не исполняется? Лучше напишите, что именно вы видите (полностью) и с какими конкретно данными запускаете.

Все проверки есть, уже разобрался:) Когда 10 часов подряд пишешь, уже голова на такие глупые моменты не работает, всё никак не мог понять. Сам себе вопрос неправильный задавал и не мог получить ответа, а это последняя задача, решил другим способом, вот только этот момент покоя не давал. В итоге прочитав всё, что комментаторы написали  голова сгенерировала всю цепочку!

"Да понять-то его, надежа-государь, не трудно" © Дьяк Феофан :)
Если все-все правильно. Т.е. в файле в строке число и перевод строки...
После (inFile >> count) читает очередной символ .get(). Он равен \n. Сравниваем с \n. Равны? Конечно! А условие? неравенство.. Значит, условие в цикле ложно, и выходим из цикла, не выполняя его тело...
Продолжать?
Представим, что у вас... ну, 123+\n. Тогда прочли 123, символ +,  неравенство выполнено, вывели число, отправились на новое выполнение цикла - если там у вас в следующей строке число, значит, повторяем действия. Если нет - inFile переходит в состояние fail, и больше никаких чтений...
А если файла нет? Не открылся? Чтения не будет, ни одного, ни другого. Вернее, второе чтение вернет eof, не равное \n, так что цикл выведет значение в count - случайное, и продолжит делать то же самое, пока его не остановят...
Все прочие неприятности рассматриваются аналогично...
Типа наброска на псевдокоде, как работает
while ( condition ) statement;

Вот так:
start:
    if condition == true then
        statement;
        goto start;
    endif
 quit:

